# i want the first two figure has to be in different tag and last two in different using XSLT

Tags: json, xml, xslt

I'm having 4 consecutive figures, in that first two figures have to come with text tag and last two figures come with caption tag by using XSLT,

My Input XML file is:

```
<images>
<image>
<url>insulin.jpg</url>
<caption>Caption Fig – Text Here</caption>
</image>
<image>
<url>medicine.jpg</url>
<caption>Caption Fig – Text Here</caption>
</image>
<image>
<url>power.jpg</url>
<caption>Caption Fig – Text Here</caption>
</image>
<image>
<url>injection.jpg</url>
<caption>Caption Fig – Text Here</caption>
</image>
</images>
```

XSLT i used as:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0">

<xsl:template match="images">
images: [
<xsl:apply-templates/>
]
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="images/image">
<xsl:if test="position() != 1">,</xsl:if>
{
<xsl:apply-templates/>
}
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="image/url">
    <xsl:text>"url": "img/</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="tokenize(., '/')[last()]"/>",
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="image/caption">
    "caption": "<xsl:apply-templates/>",
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm getting output as:

```
images: [

    {
    "url": "img/insulin.jpg",

    "caption": "Caption Fig – Text Here",

    }
,
    {
    "url": "img/medicine.jpg",

    "caption": "Caption Fig – Text Here",

    }
,
    {
    "url": "img/power.jpg",

    "caption": "Caption Fig – Text Here",

    }
,
    {
    "url": "img/injection.jpg",

    "caption": "Caption Fig – Text Here",

    }

    ]
```

But i want the first two images needs to come with text tag along with caption and last 2 figures remain same

Expected Json output:

```
images: [

    {
    "url": "img/insulin.jpg",

    "caption": {

    "text": "Caption Fig – Text Here",

    }

    }
,
    {
    "url": "img/medicine.jpg",

    "caption": {

    "text": "Caption Fig – Text Here",

    }

    }
,
    {
    "url": "img/power.jpg",

    "caption": "Caption Fig – Text Here",

    }
,
    {
    "url": "img/injection.jpg",

    "caption": "Caption Fig – Text Here",

    }

    ]
```

Please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you have more than 4 images? What is the actual logic for deciding what should have "text" and what should have "caption"?

Comment: @TimC For this type of article having only 4 images, not more than that. The first two images indicates the caption with the color information and last two captions with normal texts. So only i want to differentiate for first two with caption along text and last two with caption only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this, is add a higher priority template to match `caption` elements that occur under the first two `image` elements selected

```
<xsl:template match="image[position() &lt;= 2]/caption" priority="2">
    "text": "<xsl:apply-templates/>",
</xsl:template>
```

For this to work though, you should change the `<xsl:apply-templates/>` in the template matching `images` to explicitly select `image` elements

```
<xsl:template match="images">
images: [
<xsl:apply-templates select="image" />
]
</xsl:template>
```

This is because otherwise it may pick up whitespace nodes, and affect the position check in the new template (as the position() refers to the position in the selected node set, not necessarily the position in the document).

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="images">
images: [
<xsl:apply-templates select="image" />
]
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="images/image">
<xsl:if test="position() != 1">,</xsl:if>
{
<xsl:apply-templates/>
}
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="image/url">
    <xsl:text>"url": "img/</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="tokenize(., '/')[last()]"/>",
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="image[position() &lt;= 2]/caption" priority="2">
    "text": "<xsl:apply-templates/>",
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="image/caption">
    "caption": "<xsl:apply-templates/>",
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```